# Global Variables in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, global

I'm new to Javascript and the following code is confusing the hell out of me. By my understanding, you can assign values to global variables by dropping the var in front of them, and you don't need to define any initial value when you declare the global in the first place. However, why is the following code not working? (By not working I mean that the call to document.write within main() spits out "undefined" for "ulat").

```
var ulat;

function write(latitude) {
    ulat = latitude;
    document.write("<h1> This works:" + ulat + "</h1>");
}

function getloc() {

            if (navigator.geolocation) {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
                function(position) {
                    write(position.coords.latitude);
                },
                function (error) {
                    switch(error.code) {
                        case error.TIMEOUT:
                            alert ('Timeout');
                            break;
                        case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
                            alert ('Position unavailable');
                            break;
                        case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
                            alert ('Permission denied');
                            break;
                        case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
                            alert ('Unknown error');
                            break;
                    }
                });

            }
            else {
                alert("Geolocation is not supported by your web browser.");                 
            }       
}


function main() {
      getloc();
      document.write("<h1> This doesn't work: " + ulat + "</h1>");
}
```

Any help? Thanks!

Comment: I would recommend not creating a function called `write` when you acknowledge the existence of `document.write`

Comment: It is a good practice to be more specific when you say "not working"

Comment: I changed the name to write purely for posting here, in my actual implementation it has a different name. And by not working the "doesn't work" variable spits out "undefined"

Answer (score 4):

[`getCurrentPosition`](http://www.w3.org/TR/geolocation-API/#get-current-position) is *asynchronous*. It doesn't run when you call it, it *starts* running when you call it. So when `main` checks for a value, the success callback hasn't been called, and nothing has been assigned to `ulat`.

So here's what your code does:

1. `main` gets called
2. `main` calls `getloc`
3. `getloc` sees that geolocation is available and *starts* a geolocation request. Then it returns immediately.
4. `main` outputs the value of `ulat`, which is still `undefined`.
5. *Some time later*, your `success` callback (or, of course, failure) gets called. At that point, I'm a bit surprised that your page doesn't go blank, because you'll be calling `document.write` after the main parse, which implies a `document.open`, which tears down the page and starts with a blank slate. But I don't use `document.write` often enough to remember all the vagaries...

Comment: That makes sense. So what would I do to work around it? My endgame for this code would be to get global variables for the lat and long to be able to use in other places (namely, to display on the site as well as add to a google maps)

Comment: @Dan: Remove the `document.write` calls and you're golden, eventually `ulat` will have the value (if the geo call works). You can't use `document.write` after the main parse of the page is complete, so you'll want to use the [DOM API](http://www.w3.org/DOM/DOMTR) or your favorite library -- like [jQuery](http://jquery.com), [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org), [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/), [Closure](http://code.google.com/closure/library), or [any of several others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JavaScript_libraries) -- to modify the contents of the page post-rendering.

Comment: @Dan: I would recommend avoiding global variables, though. If you put your entire script inside a scoping function, you can have all the local variables within that function you want, without the potential for conflicting with other things in the global namespace, which is already *really* cluttered (esp. on IE). Here's an example of using a scoping function (code at the bottom of the HTML pane): http://jsbin.com/usoca3/2/edit

Answer (score 0):

You need to call main:
'main();'

Comment: main is called, there are other operations within it that work fine

Answer (score -1):

`var` is for local variables. For global variables give the reference alone or as `window.reference`.  Try modifying your code to remove the first line `var ulat;`.

Comment: `var` is as much for globals as for locals. Mind you, globals are to be avoided.